# Create a preview of html page in html page

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to create an html page containing preview or scaled view of some html pages. I tried to implement this using iframe and scaling the iframe. By display it is looking good.But even after iframe is scaled it takes the width and height of iframe content. Is there any solution for this?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #viewCollasheRow1 {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 35%;
    }

    .viewCollasheColumn1 {
        width: 445px;
        height: 192px;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .viewCollasheColumn1Content {
        width: 1775px;
        height: 760px;
        -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
        -o-transform: scale(0.25);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
        transform: scale(0.25);
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <
        <table id="viewCollasheRow1">
            <tr>
                <td class="viewCollasheColumn1"><iframe id="viewLabelFrame"
                        class="viewCollasheColumn1Content" src="./iframe1.html"
                        scrolling="no"></iframe></td>
                <td class="viewCollasheColumn1"><iframe id="viewLabelFrame"
                        class="viewCollasheColumn1Content" src="./iframe1.html"
                        scrolling="no"></iframe></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Iframe content html page

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#testDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be realy helpful.

Comment: Can you post a working solution on Jsbin, jsFiddle, or Codepen?

Comment: @locoMotion proper recommendation should be - add [MCVE] inline and preferably provide StackSnippet/jsFiddle... (see discussion on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302280/stack-snippets-vs-pastebin-jsfiddle-and-jsbin)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Noted for next time, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to give the iframe a height of 100% and the parent div the desired height, I believe you'll get the desired effect.

An excerpt from your css:

```
.viewCollasheColumn1Content {
    width: 1775px;
    height: 100%;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    transform: scale(0.25);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9sc3eqvk/

Maybe I misunderstand your question though.
The iframe's parent div will control the iframe's height and what is visible. Setting the iframe to 100% ensures that it fills the parent div.